# Handlebars : What is the best way to pass multiple parameters to a registerHelper function?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

I am using Handlebars to render data in a table.

One of the data items needs processing, which takes a few parameters into account in order to provide outcome.

The templated text example :

```
{{getOutputByParameters param1=DataFieldName1 param2=DataFieldName2}}
```

And corresponding registerHelper would be written as:

```
var __this = this;
Handlebars.registerHelper('getOutputByParameters', function(params){ __this.getOutputByParameters(params.hash.param1, params.hash.param2)})
```

I figured that handlebars would pass an array of these parameters, which I can access using hash property.

But is that the only best way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope. As per their [document](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) you can do this in many ways. I would do this way.

```
{{getOutputByParameters param1 param2}}

Handlebars.registerHelper('getOutputByParameters', function(param1, param2){ 
//do your stuff here.
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHrmC/107/)

Comment: Thanks for posting with jsFiddle, it's really awesome to see answer with demo -- live!!!

Comment: Sorry @user10, I don't know why I didn't mark your reply as answer, but better late then never done.